# Firefox extension/addon to click on given links?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

Is there some extension/addon that would click, every so often, on given links?

I need it to keep open a page that auto logouts me if I don't do anything for 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) has an auto-reload feature you can set for individual tabs. Right click the page >> Reload Tab Every >> 5 Minutes (or choose another/custom interval).